# Error LNK2019 despite proper installation and proper code syntax with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, linker-errors

I am new to Visual studio and c++ in general but have the basic knowledge for programming. The issue is I am having the same problem with Linker every single time i run code that integrates opencv functions. I have the following code:

and I always get errors related to LNK2019 and the object of the file i run. see image below

[image]

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

try {
if(argc !=2) 
    return -1;



cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(! image.data){

cout << "could not open or find the image" << endl;
return -1;}

cv::namedWindow("Display Window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::imshow( " Display Window", image);

cv::waitKey(3000);
return 0;
} catch(cv::Exception& e) {
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
std::cout << "exception caught: " << err_msg << std::endl;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you know that it's properly installed? And are you using cmake or have you added headers and lib files manually?

Comment: yeah sorry for the vagueness. I have tested out some programs that utilize opencv functions before and they have worked with no problem. I added the headers and lib files manually following the documentation of opencv with Visual studio. It seems like it has some moodswings, some programs work with no problem, others yield these errors.

Comment: This looks like a problem with the lib files. These should be all listed as additional dependencies in the project configuration dialog. Maybe a typo somewhere? If you've used the method with a global environment variable %(OPENCV_DIR), you should also try specifying the absolute path directly in VS instead.

Comment: ok I thought i already did it for my version of opencv including all the ones for the debug and release modes. the global environment variable could be the problem. I have just tried to compile my program using cmd and the cl /EHsc command, however the compiler doesn't recognize the path of the include file. is it the fault of a badly defined Global environment variable  ? I'll tinker around a bit, thank you for the pointers.